# Is there any way to convert PSObject to string in C# while working with Powershell Api

Tags: c#, tostring, powershell-4.0, psobject

I need to convert PSObject to String(). Is there any standard way available to do this task? Somehow powershell also does ToString() or spits out a readable stream on ISE console. 
I used PSSerializer.Serialize(PSObject) but it serializes everything. I want in my application seemlessly everything shown in a way the way Powershell does.

Is there anyway to convert PSObject to a.readable string. At the moment when I use following line of code

```
PSObject.ToString()
```

or

```
PSObject.BaseObject.ToString()
```

both just print out complete type name. ( e.g. "System.Collection.HashTable" )
But I want complete displayed contents to see the way powershell exposes.C#

Answer (score 1):

You could get PowerShell to format it for you.

```
foreach (PSObject obj in myPsObjects)
{
    var formattedObj =
        System.Management.Automation.PowerShell
        .Create()
        .AddCommand("Write-Output").AddArgument(obj)
        .AddCommand("Out-String")
        .Invoke();

    string message = string.Join(" ", formattedObj);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```